# Database file .sdf does not update after closing application

Tags: c#, sdf

I am creating a Desktop application using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2008. I am using a .sdf file as my database. My problem is that when I am making changes to my records (add new, deleted, updated) then the changes reflects only while my application is running. When I restart the application then I am not getting my changes.

I am using the default connection string

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString;
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
con.Open();
```

The value given by Visual Studio for this database is

> Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data.sdf

I don't know what mistake I am doing, but all the queries are executing.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you run from VS.NET, it is copying the sdf file from the solution into your bin folder, and overwriting the bin/sdf file that was there from the last run.  Change your sdf file's properties to "copy if newer" instead of "copy always".

Comment: Try setting it to the "don't copy" option (not sure if that is exactly what it's called) and see if that fixes the problem.  If that works, then you'll need to remember to change it whenever you update your db schema.

Comment: i think this solves the problem for the moment.. i have to work some more and let u know whether this is the right answer... it also gave some error.. so i have to copy the database from debug folder to bin/debug folder else it does not copy by itself...  I will let u  know shortly about the final results.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check you Application Folders and Make sure you are calling your database file from your bin file where it is located.

something like:

```
string startPath = Application.StartupPath;


var filepath = startPath + "\\" + "Database.sdf";

private SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;",filepath);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

explores solutions occurs if you have not set to 'Copy always' the 'Copy to Output Directory' of database.sdf

The current connection string and field application, and can not be changed and will be called each time to connect to DataBase

Bye

Comment: 'Copy to Output Directory' is set to 'Copy if newer' by default.. is that correct..